# Display the same maintenance page for any request

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I made a static "site under maintenance" page. I want that, for a particular vhost, that page is displayed for any URL request. If I just switch the vhost to the directory containing the page, requests to index.html will hit the page, but others will throw 404 error.

So how to display that page for any URL under a certain vhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.html [L]
```

Done! Every request will be rewritten to index.html. You can even do `[L,R=302]` to create a temporary redirect, to be nicer.

Comment: Do not forget to set up proper expire rules for your domain!

Comment: @chx actually this seems to cause an infinite redirect loop......

Comment: @chx I added a line, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @cstamas correct. Also "RewriteRule ^(index\.htm){0}$ /index.html [L,R=302]" works

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the feedback of the other answer here is an alternate that doesn't get indexed by spiders

```
RedirectMatch 503 ^/(?!index\.html|yaml|work|css|screen)
ErrorDocument 503 /index.html
Header always set Retry-After "18000"
```

yaml, work, css and screen are directories referenced by index.html

Comment: An alternative way to avoid getting the maintenance page indexed is to  add it the robots.txt file(s).